# How to post a URL encoded dictionary within a strongly typed object from Refit

Tags: c#, .net-core, postman, refit

I am trying to replicate a URL Encoded Form Data request that contains a dictionary from Postman into [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) but I cannot get it (Refit) to produce the same encoded data. See the comparisons below and notice that the encoded data from Refit has seemingly done `.ToString()` on the dictionary rather than encoding it the same way that Postman has.

Is this functionality built in to Refit or will I somehow have to implement a custom encoder? It seems like this would be a fairly common use-case so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

### Postman

Request and Url Encoded form data:

[image: Postman Request]

```
Body=Test&AllowContact=true&Context=postman&QuestionsAnswers%5B0%5D.Key=Question&QuestionsAnswers%5B0%5D.Value=2
```

### Refit

API definition:

```cs
[Post("/feedback")]
Task<ApiResponse<HttpResponseMessage>> PostFeedback(
    [Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)] PostFeedbackRequest request);
```

Request definition:

```cs
public record PostFeedbackRequest(
    string Body,
    bool AllowContact,
    string Context,
    IDictionary<string, int>? QuestionsAnswers = null);
```

API call:

```cs
var response = await Api.PostFeedback(
    new PostFeedbackRequest(
        "Test",
        true,
        "Refit",
        new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
          ["Question"] = 2,
        }));
```

Url Encoded form data:

```
Body=Test&AllowContact=True&Context=Refit&QuestionsAnswers=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Int32%5D
```

Comment: Not really an answer but just pointing out it is not the same thing - in Postman you do not have a dictionary. I guess it would also work if in Refit you'd use a `Dictionary<string, object> QuestionsAnswers` instead of the custom model. The dictionary would then be populated with the exact same values as in Postman so Body = Test, etc.. QuestionAnswers[0].Key = Question ...

Comment: Changing to Dictionary<string, object> resulted in essentially the same form data: Body=Test&AllowContact=True&Context=Refit&QuestionsAnswers=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say it would probably work if you used a Dictionary<string,object> instead of PostFeedbackRequest record. This is based on the example in their documentation.  My guess is that you could create a custom class derived from Dictionary and override .ToString on it so that when ToString is called, it produces the desired output.